# Как на странице ошибок получить имя сайта на языке оригинала?

Tags: php, html, ссылки, href

Нужно перевести фразу на странице ошибок, чтобы в ней ссылка вела на главную страницу сайта.

```
<p>
    <?php
    printf(
    /* translators: %s: a link to the embedded site */
    __( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try visiting %s directly?' ),
'<strong><a href="' . esc_url( home_url() ) . '">' . esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . '</a></strong>');?></p>
```

Однако код ссылки выводится за абзацем.

```
<p>По данному адресу ничего не найдено. Попробуйте перейти на сайт <a href="#"></a>.</p>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате тестирования выяснил, что на странице ошибок в принципе не отрабатывают функции `bloginfo( 'name' )` и `get_bloginfo( 'name' )`
Вот такая запись выводит пустой абзац

```
$name = bloginfo( 'name' );
  echo '<p>'.$name.'</p>';
```

Хотя, к примеру, вот такая функция отрабатывает и выводит ссылку

```
$url = esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) );
       echo '<p>'.$url.'</p>';
```

Можно ли как-то обойти этот момент?

Comment: возможно во время перевода %s конвертируется на html символы.

Comment: @Владислав а теперь вопрос в том как это исправить?

Comment: если вывести англоязычную фразу тоже в конец встает ссылка?

Comment: вобщем я бы сначала захардкодил результат и вывел в html, если все ок, захардкодил подстановку значений, которые идут вторым параметром print_r, если все ок, значит надо рыться в методе __()

Comment: @Skywave `. esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) .` вот этот участок кода не отрабатывает.

Comment: осталось понять что в нем не так =)

Comment: @Skywave это да.. можно, конечно, же заменить на надпись, но на будет тогда ток на 1 языке и теряется тогда весь смысл перевода

Comment: В результате тестирования выяснил, что на странице ошибок в принципе не отрабатывают функции bloginfo( 'name' ) и get_bloginfo('name' )
Вот такая запись выводит пустой абзац
`$name = bloginfo( 'name' );
  echo '<p>'.$name.'</p>';`
Хотя, к примеру, вот такая функция отрабатывает и выводит ссылку
`$url = esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) );
       echo '<p>'.$url.'</p>';`
Можно ли как-то обойти этот момент?